# Can't check if my PC meets the minimum Windows 11 requirements "For info about getting windows 11, Contact your IT admin."

Tags: user-accounts, windows-11

I'm getting "For info about getting windows 11, Contact your IT admin." when using the Windows PC Health Check app to see if my PC meets the requirements to run Windows 11.

Despite having no "Work or School" accounts. See the following screenshot.

[image]

My Windows License and build version

[image]

This issue comes despite the fact I have no Work or School accounts
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for Windows 11 are still being nailed down, but more firm now is that you need for sure Secure Boot and TPM  (Trusted Platform Module). You also need DirectX 12 / WDDM2 for graphics work.

To install and Set up Windows 11, you also need a Microsoft Account. I believe you may be able to change this later.

You need to check the status of your Education version and school account (why does this appear). You need a Microsoft Account to install and set up Windows 11.

You need to be able to run the Windows 11 Readiness Checks. Even though Readiness Checks are moving they provide a decent starting point.

"Why can't I check?"

Run the GitHub app fully referenced toward the end of this post.

So far, my take on Windows 11 is a much higher starting bar that means non-UEFI dual boot, non TPM Desktop computers just will not make the cut to Windows 11.

Windows 10 end of life at this point is October 2025

[Windows 10 End of Life](https://www.theverge.com/2021/6/14/22533018/microsoft-windows-10-end-support-date)

> Microsoft is ending support for Windows 10 on October 14th, 2025. It
> will mark just over 10 years since the operating system was first
> introduced. Microsoft revealed the retirement date for Windows 10 in
> an updated support life cycle page for the OS. Thurrott reports that
> this is the first time Microsoft has ever described the end of support
> for Windows 10.

Take note of the chart in the article directly below as it presents a good summary.

[Windows Insider Windows 11 Requirements](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/06/24/preparing-for-insider-preview-builds-of-windows-11/)

> In support of the Windows 11 hardware requirements, we’re setting the
> minimum requirements for flighting to match what is enforced within
> our media install experience (ISOs), but we recommend that PCs meet
> the full hardware requirements for the best experience when using
> Windows 11 Insider Preview builds.

[Trusted Media Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-tpm)

> Trusted Platform Module (TPM) technology is designed to provide
> hardware-based, security-related functions. A TPM chip is a secure
> crypto-processor that helps you with actions such as generating,
> storing, and limiting the use of cryptographic keys. Many TPMs include
> multiple physical security mechanisms to make it tamper resistant, and
> malicious software is unable to tamper with the security functions of
> the TPM.

Here are screen shots of things you should look at. Use Start, Run, DXDIAG to run the DirectX app.

I have shown the requirement for TPM.  This will clarify over time. EDIT:  June 27.  It now appears TPM must be version 2.

DirectX 12: The Computer must be running DirectX 12

[image: DirectX 12]

DirectX WDD2  DirectX 12 must be using WDDM2

[image]

Device Manager TPM:  There has to be a TPM2 Chip

[image: Device Manager TPM]

Secure Boot:  Secure Boot must be enabled.

[image: Secure Boot]

GitHub Windows 11 Readiness

If you are having issues running the Windows Readiness app, use the GitHub Why Not Windows 11 app.

[Why not Windows 11](https://www.windowscentral.com/whynotwin11-app-check-windows-11-hardware)

> Want more detail as to why your PC may not get Windows 11? A new free
> app called WhyNotWin11 dives much deeper than Microsoft's own attempt.
>
> Windows 11 has strict CPU and hardware requirements that are causing a
> lot of frustration. Microsoft's own PC Health Check app is getting
> better but still feels half-baked. A new free, open-source app called
> WhyNotWin11 provides much more detail for users exploring their PC's
> hardware in preparation for Windows 11.

.

[image: GitHub Windows 11 Readiness]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I had no "work or school" accounts, however I had a Microsoft Windows 10 Education license (this may have caused the issue, also others with Enterprise licenses etc may have the same issue, but it will say "Your organization manages this PC" for the prompt title).

Assigning a Microsoft account to my local administrator account got rid of this error.

[image]

To do this:

1. Settings -> Accounts -> Your info
2. Sign in with a Microsoft account instead

Then restart the Windows PC Health Check app (WindowsPCHealthCheckSetup.msi)